# why i am getting SMTP connect failed error in PHPMailer?

Tags: php

I really don't know what's wrong in my code. I am creating contact us form by which user can send email to me. I already searched all possible answer related to this topic on StackOverflow but nothing works for me... here is the code

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'libs/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$errors =[];

if(isset($_POST['name'],$_POST['email'],$_POST['message'])){
    $fields=[
        'name'=>$_POST['name'],
        'email'=>$_POST['email'],
        'message'=>$_POST['message']
    ];
    foreach($fields as $field=>$data){
        if(empty($data)){
            $errors[]='The '.$field . ' field is required.';
        }
    }
    if(empty($errors)){
        $m=new PHPMailer;
        $m->isSMTP();
        $m->SMTPAuth=true;
        $m->Host='smtp.gmail.com';
        $m->Username='...@gmail.com';//replace with your email address
        $m->Password='xxxxxxx';//replace with your password
        $m->SMTPSecure='ssl';
        $m->Port=465;

        $m->isHTML();
        $m->Subject ='Contact form Submitted';
        $m->Body='From:'.$fields['name'].'('.$fields['email'].')<p>'.$fields['message'].'</p>';

        $m->FromName='Contact';
        $m->AddAddress('someone@gmail.com','Some one');
        if ($m->send()) {
            header('Location:thanks.php');
            die();
        }else{
            $errors[]="Sorry ,Could not send email.Try again later.";
        }
    }
}else{
    $errors[]= 'Something went wrong';
}
$_SESSION['errors']=$errors;
$_SESSION['fields']=$fields;
header ('Location:index.php');
```

Comment: insert `$m->SMTPDebug = 3`

Comment: What @kuh-chan said ^^^^^  Re-run and add the log information to your question.

Comment: Also [read this page](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting) carefully.  In particular look at the section on security and verify that you have the openssl extension.